# Get value from multiple dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple dropdown menus that are the same, I need them to be the same.

```
 <select name="Obrojgoluba" id="otacmajka" class="selectbox_dodajpostojeceg" onchange="dodajpostojeceg('otac')">
  <option value="1">06557-07-681</option>
  <option value="2">07216-05-552</option>
</select>
```

This is my jQuery function to get value from that select list

```
function dodajpostojeceg(x)
{
    var ID = $('select[name="Obrojgoluba"]').val();
    alert(ID);

}
```

But problem is that it gets value from the first select list, not from others I have on my site. When I click on the first one it gets good values. but when I click on other select list on my site that are the same as first one it returns or empty or value it remembered from the first select list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using this

```
var ID = $('select[name="Obrojgoluba"]').val();
```

And it is possible as you said that there are multiple `select` on your page. So if they are having same name, above code would select the `first` one and that is what you are getting.

So you can just change the function and markup to made this code workable.

```
function dodajpostojeceg(element)
{
    var ID = $(element).val();
    alert(ID);
}
```

and call this function as like this

```
<select name="Obrojgoluba" id="otacmajka" class="selectbox_dodajpostojeceg" onchange="dodajpostojeceg(this)">
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MfXLH/)

Answer (score 1):

A strange thing to be doing, but try this:

```
function dodajpostojeceg(x)
{
    var ID = $(this).val();
    alert(ID);
}
```

As CBRoe comments, multiple identical IDs are invalid, and this may hamper your progress...

Comment: ID is not relevant here cause I'm using it just to trick something. I'm not using it to identify something important

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `jquery` lib is included and the function is defined before the `html`

```
<head>
    function dodajpostojeceg(x)
    {
        var ID = $('select[name="Obrojgoluba"]').val();
        alert(ID);
    }
</head>

<body>
    <select name="Obrojgoluba" id="otacmajka" class="selectbox_dodajpostojeceg" onchange="dodajpostojeceg('otac')">
        <option value="1">06557-07-681</option>
        <option value="2">07216-05-552</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kR8yH/

When the `html` is rendered, it will look for a function named `dodajpostojeceg()` and if it not defined, it will not be able to bind the `select` and the function

I am assuming that all the `select`s are uniquely `name`d

Comment: not working cause there is multiple select on my websites that are exactly the same. But I found answer. thanks